# .HTACCESS duplicating my link

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1&iff=$2 [L]
```

This is my php file

Index.php

```
<?php
   $ll1=$_GET["id"];
   $ll12=$_GET["iff"];
?>
<a href="Make/Mak">aaa</a><a href="Make"> bbb</a>
<?php 
if($ll1=="Make" && $ll12=="Mak"){include 'shop/index.php';} 
elseif($ll1=="Make"){include 'shop/productpreview.php';} 
?>
```

this problem is that when i click the first link(aaa) it open well with the url(https://localhost/Make/Mak)

but when i click it again, it show object not found with the url (https://localhost/Make/Make/Mak).

Please can anybody help me with why it is duplicating the first parameter?

I tried it with three parameters, it duplicated the first and the second parameters

Thank you for your time in anticipation

Comment: When you are in `https://localhost/Make/Mak` browsers thinks you are in `root/Make/` directory, so a link in that page gets the first `Make/` as it's prefix because normal URLs work based on the current directory they are in. To fix this you can use a link like this, path the link from root not current directory: `<a href="/Make/Mak">aaa</a>`

Comment: Yeah thanks alot. but i remove some information from the question not knowing that it will hunt me.

This is the real URL (https://localhost/bell/Make/Mak) and not (https://localhost/Make/Mak). I have many websites in my htdocs and one of them is bell. so when i put <a href="/Make/Mak">aaa</a> it takes me one step back which  which i do not want. My .htaccess is in my bell folder. Thank you again for your time

Comment: Night2 Thanks alot. i change it to <a href="/bell/Make/Mak">aaa</a> as you said and it worked well and perfect. i am very much grateful

Comment: Use a config file in your php codes and a set a config for full URL of your website like this or a constant: `$site_url = 'https://localhost/bell/';` You can use that variable or constant now in your codes, so later on when you change the location of the website to something like `http://www.domain.com/` you only edit 1 line of code in config file ...

Comment: You can use that variable now like this in php codes `<a href="<?php echo $site_url; ?>Make/Mak">` ... Or inject it inside the html code using `base` tag once: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 0):

try to give your href like `/Make/Mak`